# @AutoConfigureMockMvc how to set message converters

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test, mockmvc, spring-autoconfiguration

How can I specify message converters when using **@AutoConfigureMockMvc**?

Consider following example:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = SomeController.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@WithMockUser
class SomeControllerTestIT {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private SomeController controller;

    @Test
    void foo() throws Exception {

        MockMvc customMvc = standaloneSetup(resource).setMessageConverters(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter()).build();

       
        customMvc.perform(get("/some-path"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE));
    }
}
```

If I use plain **mockMvc** instead of **customMvc** then I get following exception, because *MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter* is not registered:

```
Type = org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException
```

If I use **customMvc** then test is green. So I need to apply *MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter* somehow to **mockMvc**, but I don't know how.

Please advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/24000 correct solution is using both @AutoConfigureMockMvc and @AutoConfigureWebMvc

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@AutoConfigureWebMvc
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@WithMockUser
public @interface MockMvcWithUser {
}

@SpringBootTest(classes = SomeController.class)
@MockMvcWithUser 
class SomeControllerTestIT { 
  ... // same test logic goes here
}
```